# MongoDB Atlas api returns two headers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

MongoDB Atlas API(generated a programmatic API key) returns the two headers

On authentication successful, it returns two headers on with response 401 and another one with 200 (with data)

```
curl -i -u "<username>:<apiKey>" --digest "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/<group-id>/databaseUsers/admin/<dbusername>?pretty=true"

HTTP/2 401 
www-authenticate: Digest realm="MMS Public API", domain="",     nonce="/xGsFcHm0TT69utb5fj0AQGKV85ihlY7", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth", stale=false
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 05 Aug 2019 10:28:16 GMT
content-length: 106

HTTP/2 401 
www-authenticate: Digest realm="MMS Public API", domain="",     nonce="cpvM848g/8JJfZ42OyaD7xt4365jP3kI", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth", stale=false
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 05 Aug 2019 10:28:16 GMT
content-length: 106

{
  "reason" : "Unauthorized",
  "error" : 401,
  "detail" : "You are not authorized for this resource."
}
```

It should return only one header instead of two

Answer (score 2):

That is how a digest authentication works

Kindly read the section named **Example with explanation** in the following wiki article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

Also note it's not mentioned in the docs but the username is the public key and password is the private key of the programatic api key.